# HttpErrorResponse doing a request with angular to a Laravel Backend

Tags: angular, ajax, laravel, http, jwt

Im having this error while, im trying to login in to my apllication. If i try do the petition through Postman is working good and I would like to know where is the problem, as I say the HTPP request is working on Postman and It gives me the JWT token of the authenficate user.

```
signup(user: any, gettoken : boolean): Observable<any> {

    if (gettoken != false) {
        user.gettoken = 'true';
    }

    let json = JSON.stringify(user);
    let params = 'json='+json;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this.url+'login', params, {headers: headers});
}

  onSubmit(form : any) {
    this._userService.signup(this.user, false).subscribe(
      response => {
        // Token
        if (response.status != 'error') {
          this.status = "success";
          this.token = response;

      // Objeto del usuario identificado
      this._userService.signup(this.user, true).subscribe(
        response => {
          // Token
            this.identity = response;
            console.log(this.token);
            console.log(this.identity);
        }, error => {
            this.status = "error";
            console.log(<any>error);
          
        });

    } else {
      this.status = "error";
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(<any>error);
  },
)
```

}

[htpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teya8.png)

Answer (score 0):

There error you're having indicates that `JSON.parse` is throwing. This is because your backend isn't returning JSON but a text response.

You need to set the `responseType` to `'text` :

```
return this._http.post(this.url+'login', params, {headers: headers, responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: Thank You! The thing is that i want to return identity as an object and the jwt token as text